# .bat and .ps1 keep pulling C: when running from a thumbdrive

Tags: powershell

So I am struggling with why this is happening.  I have a .bat file on a thumbdrive that runs a .ps1 file (in the same folder as it).  Pretty straightforward, the .bat file goes like this:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass LocalMachine" -force

powershell.exe -noprofile -file "%~dpn0.ps1" %*

powershell.exe -noprofile -command "Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned LocalMachine" -force
```

It runs the script in the same folder, which is great.  But then as the .ps1 file runs, I have a variable section that does:

```
$DriveLetter = (Get-Location).Drive.Name
mkdir "${DriveLetter}:\Script Folder\Subfolder\Subfolder${env:computername}"
```

And for whatever godforsaken reason, even though the thumbdrive is D: (sometimes E:, which is the sole reason for these stupid lines), when I run the script itself it pulls up D: no problem.  When I run it through the .bat?  It suddenly starts using C:

Can anybody help me figure out where this is going wrong?

I've tried pulling drive information a few different ways, I've even tried the basic .\ and it still pulled C:

Comment: It appears I needed to do the following:

setlocal
cd /d "%~dp0"

Answer (score 1):

[`Get-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-location) returns PowerShell's *current location*, which, for the [file-system provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_FileSystem_Provider), is the *working directory* for the current PowerShell session - this directory is unrelated to *where the executing script happens to be located* (which, in batch files, is reflected in `%~dpn0`).

In PowerShell scripts, the automatic [automatic `$PSScriptRoot` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psscriptroot) contains the full path to the directory in which the executing script (`*.ps1`) is located.

You can use [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path)  `-Qualifier` to extract the drive specification from it.

Alternatively, as you've discovered yourself, you can *change the working directory* to be on the same drive as the executing script before calling `Get-Location`:

- In your batch file, you can use `cd /d "%~dp0"`

  - Note that if you call your batch file from a `cmd.exe` session and do not have a `setlocal` statement at the start of your batch file, the working directory will change for the `cmd.exe` session too.
- Or, in your PowerShell script, you can use `Set-Location -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot`

  - Since you're calling PowerShell via its CLI, i.e. in a *child process*, this change by definition doesn't affect the calling batch file (or the latter's calling `cmd.exe` session).
  - However, if you were to call your PowerShell script *directly from PowerShell*, a `Set-Location` call would invariably affect the entire PowerShell session; that is, PowerShell has *no* `setlocal` analog with respect to its *current location* (working directory).<sup>[1]</sup>

To demonstrate the `Split-Path` solution, along with a streamlined batch file:

Batch file:

```bash
@echo off & setlocal

powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -file "%~dpn0.ps1" %*
```

Note:

- No need to temporarily change the *persistent* [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies).
- Using the `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter of [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, you can set the execution policy on a *per-call* basis (assuming that your execution policy isn't GPO-controlled).

PowerShell script:

```bash
$DriveLetter = Split-Path -Qualifier $PSScriptRoot
mkdir "${DriveLetter}:\Script Folder\Subfolder\Subfolder${env:computername}"
```

Note:

- `mkdir` produces output, namely a `[DirectoryInfo]` instance representing the newly created directory; prepend `$null = ...` to suppress the output.

---

<sup>[1] By contrast, *variables* (and other definitions) are *implicitly* script-local in PowerShell.</sup>